# iPhone SDK shake and vibrate

Tags: iphone

how can use vibrate when iPhone shaking ? 
here is my code :

```
#pragma mark -
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer 
        didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
   {
        if (acceleration.x > kAccelerationThreshold 
            || acceleration.y > kAccelerationThreshold
            || acceleration.z > kAccelerationThreshold) {


  **//Vibrate it !** 

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Make sure to add the AudioToolbox framework.